# spark expression rename the column list after aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written below code to group and aggregate the columns

```
 val gmList = List("gc1","gc2","gc3")
 val aList = List("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5")

 val cype = "first"

 val exprs = aList.map((_ -> cype )).toMap

 dfgroupBy(gmList.map (col): _*).agg (exprs).show
```

but this create a columns with appending aggregation name in all column as shown below

so I want to alias that name   first(val1) -> val1, I want to make this code  generic as part of exprs

```
  +----------+----------+-------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
 |    gc1   |  gc2     | gc3         |        first(val1)      |      first(val2)|       first(val3)          |       first(val4)      |       first(val5) |
 +----------+----------+-------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to alias the aggregated columns to the original column names in a subsequent `select`.  I would also suggest generalizing the single aggregate function (i.e. `first`) to a list of functions, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 10, "a1", "a2", "a3"),
  (1, 10, "b1", "b2", "b3"),
  (2, 20, "c1", "c2", "c3"),
  (2, 30, "d1", "d2", "d3"),
  (2, 30, "e1", "e2", "e3")
).toDF("gc1", "gc2", "val1", "val2", "val3")

val gmList = List("gc1", "gc2")
val aList = List("val1", "val2", "val3")

// Populate with different aggregate methods for individual columns if necessary
val fList = List.fill(aList.size)("first")

val afPairs = aList.zip(fList)
// afPairs: List[(String, String)] = List((val1,first), (val2,first), (val3,first))

df.
  groupBy(gmList.map(col): _*).agg(afPairs.toMap).
  select(gmList.map(col) ::: afPairs.map{ case (v, f) => col(s"$f($v)").as(v) }: _*).
  show
// +---+---+----+----+----+
// |gc1|gc2|val1|val2|val3|
// +---+---+----+----+----+
// |  2| 20|  c1|  c2|  c3|
// |  1| 10|  a1|  a2|  a3|
// |  2| 30|  d1|  d2|  d3|
// +---+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly change the way you are generating the expression and use the function `alias` in there:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val aList = List("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5")
val exprs = aList.map(c => first(col(c)).alias(c) )
dfgroupBy( gmList.map(col) : _*).agg(exprs.head , exprs.tail: _*).show
```

Comment: here the problem is "first" also fixed , I want to make that also genric, like exprs should take any aggregation such as "first" "mean"  "min" etc

Comment: How would you relate which function should be applied to which column ?

Comment: in my requirement I want to apply same function for all columns

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic version that will work with any aggregate functions and doesn't require naming your aggregate columns up front. Build your grouped `df` as you normally would, then use:

```
val colRegex = raw"^.+\((.*?)\)".r
val newCols = df.columns.map(c => col(c).as(colRegex.replaceAllIn(c, m => m.group(1))))
df.select(newCols: _*)
```

This will extract out only what is inside the parentheses, regardless of what aggregate function is called (e.g. `first(val) -> val`, `sum(val) -> val`, `count(val) -> val`, etc.).